# I am storing date in my table.I want to select data and in that if there is no date in table then corresponging field to date should be 0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tables : CollegeReview,

Fields - CollegeID ,Review Desc, ReviewDate,

I have created report for this table that shows:

```
Date          No Of Reviews
12-jan-2012         10
13-jan-2012         8
15-jan-2012         2
```

This query is not printing date - 14-jan-2012

I want this report like...

```
Date          No Of Reviews
12-jan-2012         10
13-jan-2012         8
14-jan-2012         0
15-jan-2012         2
```

There is date field in my table. But if there is no entry for particular date then i should return 0.

sql query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(ReviewDate AS DATE),100)AS 'Date',COUNT(*) AS 'Review(s)' FROM Reviews 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(ReviewDate AS DATE),100)
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(ReviewDate AS DATE),100) desc
```

Comment: are you giving date range in the query

Comment: NO, I AM NOT GIVING DATE RANGE

Comment: PLEASE SHOW US YOUR QUERY

Comment: @jomsk1e i have edited my question and added query there

Comment: Is it a monthly report?what dates are you targeting to get in report?Is it till the max date in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what you need to do is create additional table with dates that you want.

```
CREATE TABLE Dates
([date] date)


declare @stDate date, @endDate date, @insertDate date
set @stDate='01.01.2000';--choose your possible dates
set @endDate='01.01.2020';
set @insertDate=@stDate;

while (@insertDate<@endDate)
begin
insert into Dates values(@insertDate)
set @insertDate=DATEADD(d,1,@insertDate)
end
```

Now you can write your query using `RIGHT JOIN` with `Dates` table

```
SELECT Dates.[date] as 'Date',
COUNT(*) AS 'Review(s)' 
FROM Reviews right join Dates on Dates.[date]=CAST(ReviewDate AS DATE)
where Dates.[date]>'01.01.2014' and Dates.[date]<'01.02.2014' --use your dates here
    GROUP BY Dates.[date], CAST(ReviewDate AS DATE)
    ORDER BY Dates.[date] desc
```

This additional table is quite useful. You may create this table in `master` Db and use it in all your reports as well.

Comment: Thanks @MikkaRin, Is it possible without creating additional table,

Comment: You may create function that will return set of dates that you need (like in `Dates table`) - for example `fn GetDates(@stDate, @endDate)`. In this case you no need to create additional table. That's all I can suggest you.

Comment: how can i assign current date to @endDate

Comment: just use `cast(getdate() as DATE)` instead of `@endDate`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for dates that would have a count of zero, there are no rows in the input table (`CollegeReview`).

Therefore there is no data to include to fill in the gaps within any query to the database.

Rather you'll need to post-process the results of your query (for this purpose a collection of {Date,Count} called `queryResult`).

Generating a list of missing dates to fill in is then easy:

```
var existingDates = queryResult.Select(x => x.Date).ToArray();
// if queryResult is known to be sorted replace with .First() and .Last().
var startDate = existingDates.Minimum();
var endDate = existingDates.Maximum();
var dateCount = (endDate - startDate).Days;

var missingDates = Enumerable.Range(0, dateCount)
                             .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
                             .Where(d => !existingDates.Contains(d));

var allData = queryResult.Concat(missingDates.Select(d => new { Date = d, Count = 0}));
```

NB. If you otherwise know the date range (parameters, current date, …) then use that rather looking at the range of results.

Comment: This could also be done in an SP (build a temp table of the complete range of dates and perform an outer join). But you did tag the question C# so I assume a C# answer was acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to give accurate answer without more info about the query you're using. However, I suspect that you're joining the tables in your query incorrectly. You should use the correct **outer join** to get the results you want.

Otherwise, this query should return the results you described:

```
SELECT ReviewDate AS 'Date', COUNT(*) AS 'No Of Reviews'
FROM CollegeReview
GROUP BY ReviewDate
```

**EDIT**: OK, now that you added your query. The issue is you are trying to show data that is not in the table. To do so, you have to provide the data by yourself. But you will have to specify the date range as you don't want to create a list of infinite date. The range can be derived directly from the data in your table, for instance `BETWEEN MIN(ReviewDate) AND MAX(ReviewDate)`. Then you can join this list to your query. Something like this:

```
SELECT lod.day AS 'Date', COUNT(*) AS 'No Of Reviews'
FROM CollegeReview AS cr
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(DateTime) IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) THEN 31
    WHEN MONTH(DateTime) IN (4, 6, 9, 11) THEN 30
    ELSE DATEDIFF(dd, CAST(YEAR(DateTime) AS varchar(4)) + '-02-01', CAST(YEAR(DateTime) AS varchar(4)) + '-03-01')
    END AS 'day'
    FROM dual) AS list_of_days ON lod.day = cr.ReviewDate
GROUP BY cr.ReviewDate
```

The code can be slightly different depending on your database engine.